¿Cuál puede ser una definición no circular de acuerdo?
Buscando en Google, RAE, etc me salen las siguientes definiciones de acuerdo

Acuerdo: acción y efecto de acordar
Acordar: Determinar o resolver algo de común acuerdo

(No pongo el link a Google porque me sale en la sugerencias de Google para "acuerdo significado")
En RAE:

Acuerdo: convenio entre dos o más partes
Convenio: Acuerdo o pacto

Acuerdo RAE
Convenio RAE
No llego a ninguna explicación real con definiciones circulares.
¿Cuál puede ser una definición no circular de acuerdo?
